# DARTFMT messes up @Component decorator formatting

Tags: dart, angular-dart

This is a bug, so I don't know if I'm posting in the right place. Please let me know where to post instead if this is the wrong place.

What you see below is the exact formatting produced by running dartfmt on the code below. As you can see, the formatting of the @Component decorator is atrocious.

I'm using Dartfmt 1.0.12 as provided by the latest Dart 2 developer release.

```js
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'routes.dart';

@Component(selector: 'my-app', templateUrl: 'app_component.html', directives: [
  routerDirectives
], providers: [
  const ClassProvider(Routes),
], styleUrls: [
  'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css'
])
class AppComponent {
  final Routes routes;

  AppComponent(this.routes);
}
```

Comment: That really looks messed up. You can report it at https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks! I posted it there.

Comment: issue reported here: https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/issues/687

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Insert a comma just before the closing bracket of `@Component(...)`** and you'll probably get what you expect.

This is what dartfmt produces once the comma is inserted:

```dart
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'routes.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [routerDirectives],
  providers: [
    const ClassProvider(Routes),
  ],
  styleUrls: ['package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css'],
)
class AppComponent {
  final Routes routes;

  AppComponent(this.routes);
}
```